# Добавление новых данных в БД c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Всем привет. Мне нужно добавить новые данные в существующую БД. Мой код:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-7BKNE6D\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Matveev_VT-31;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {


                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Customers] (Name, Address, Phone, ContactPerson) Values(@Name, @Address, @Phone, @ContactPerson)");
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", textBox1.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address", textBox2.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Phone", textBox3.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ContactPerson", textBox4.Text);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                this.customersTableAdapter.Fill(this._Matveev_VT_31DataSet1.Customers);
                customersDataGridView.Update();
                customersDataGridView.Refresh();

            }

        }
    }
        }
    }
```

Выдаёт 4 ошибки:
Ошибка  CS1061  "Form7" не содержит определения для "customersTableAdapter", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "customersTableAdapter", принимающий тип "Form7" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).
Ошибка  CS1061  "Form7" не содержит определения для "_Matveev_VT_31DataSet1", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "_Matveev_VT_31DataSet1", принимающий тип "Form7" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).
Ошибка  CS0117  "customersDataGridView" не содержит определение для "Update".
Ошибка  CS0117  "customersDataGridView" не содержит определение для "Refresh".
В чём проблема? Все бд подключены работают корректно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё правильно - Вам выдаются "правильные ошибки".

Смотрим в код. Там процедура ДОБАВЛЕНИЯ данных, которая, навскидку, написана и работает корректно.

Только три строки в ней -

```
this.customersTableAdapter.Fill(this._Matveev_VT_31DataSet1.Customers);
customersDataGridView.Update();
customersDataGridView.Refresh();
```

уже не относятся к добавлению данных и являются лишними.

Удалите их - и у вас по нажатию на кнопку новые данные будут записываться в базу инсертом.

А то, что написано в этих трех строках - это уже не относится к доабвлению данных. Это - процесс отображения заполненного дата адаптера на форме - чтобы вы на форме увидели дата грид с новыми данными.

Но ведь вы страшиваете не об этом, а о добавлени? Добавление - будет работать.

Советую процесс обновления дата адаптера сделать отдельным от операций с данными, например, вынеся его еще в один блок `usiung{}`

Ну, и об ошибках, про котрые говирится дальше.

Итак. Добавлять - умеем, всё правильно написано, очень простая задача - вызывать один insert с параметрами.

Отображать - задача уже более сложная.

"Отображатель" говорит вам - "хозяин, я умею данные показывать, добавлять и удалять... только ты мне скажи, какие SQL команды для этого надо вызвать!".

То есть, логика того компонента, который называется customersTableAdapter - это логика "прослойки" между датагридом customersDataGridView и базой данных.

По большому счёту, эта прослойка не так уж плоха: она однйо стороной смотрит на дата грид, и когда в нём пользователь делает операцию "вставить строку" - она генерирует для базы данных insert. "Удалить строку" - прослойка генерирует "Delete". Но разобраться с её логикой - это не так просто.

Самое простое для начала работы - вообще выбросить из системы data adapter, и обходиться data grid и самой базой. Заполнять и обновлять data grid вручную. Это потребует написать больше кода, зато этот код будет делать ровно то, что Вам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Очень доходчиво и понятно объяснили!